# Which one is right "I must or mustn't be back home before 8pm"?

Tags: grammar

> On weekdays I must get up early because I have to take the school bus at 7.10. When I get up at 6.15, I have lots of time; I can take a shower and eat breakfast. But I usually get up at 6.45, so usually I must hurry to catch my bus. I come back from school at 2.30. Usually I needn't make lunch because my mom cooks for us. But I must wash the dishes and tidy up the kitchen afterwards. After lunch I must do my homework. But when I've finished my homework, I can do whatever I like - watch TV, go outside or meet my friends. However, I **....must or mustn't....** be back at home before 8pm.
>
> I love weekends because I can sleep as long as I like. Also, I needn't go to school! However, I must help my mum at home. I must clean the bathrooms and wash the car. Luckily, I needn't work in the garden - that's my sister's job.

This is a part of an exercise and I think that *must* is correct, but the answer in the key was *mustn't*. Can somebody explain why it is mustn't?

Comment: We need more context to properly answer this (I can think of reasons both why you *must* and *must not* be back at 8). What's so important about that 8 pm time?

Comment: On weekdays I must get up early because I have to take the school bus at 7.10.
When I get up at 6.15, I have lots of time; I can take a shower and eat
breakfast. But I usually get up at 6.45, so usually I must hurry to catch my
bus.
I come back from school at 2.30. Usually I needn't make lunch because my
mom cooks for us. But I must wash the dishes and tidy up the kitchen
afterwards.
After lunch I must do my homework. But when I've finished my homework, I
can do whatever I like - watch TV, go outside or meet my friends. However, I
must or mustn't be back at home before 8pm.

Comment: I love weekends because I can sleep as long as I like. Also, I
needn't go to school! However, I must help my mum at home. I
must clean the bathrooms and wash the car. Luckily, I needn't
work in the garden - that's my sister's job.

Comment: This is the whole text.

Comment: There is nothing at all that indicates one or the other is the right choice. Both could be appropriate. (Something is happening at 8 p.m. that you need to be home for—or renovations are taking place and you *shouldn't* return before then.)

Comment: _Cultural context_, as well as the mention of watching television as an option for the evening, indicates that it's more likely the speaker **must** be home before 8pm than that they **mustn't**. Such a deadline is called a curfew, and they're fairly common for young students (at least here in the U.S.). If the speaker needed to stay out of the house until 8pm on a weeknight, that would be unusual in a way that the text _does not_ indicate.

Answer (score 2):

I think you're right, "I **must** be back at home before 8" makes far more sense.

If "I **mustn't** be back at home before 8" were true, the person would have to stay out of the house until at least 8 o'clock, and not come home until later than that.

Edit: There *is* reason to believe that **must** is correct. The narrator in the text couldn't stay home and do their homework if they **mustn't** be home before 8. There's no ambiguity at all.

Comment: Thank you very much